# Como enviar parâmetros via post em java usando HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http-request

estou com um problema para enviar por meio de um método POST em java parâmetros usando o HttpURLConnection.
Estive tentando de algumas formas e pesquisei bastante, mas nenhum modo funcionou para mim. Deixarei o código abaixo para que vocês me indiquem possíveis modificações que podem ser feitas.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class HttpTeste {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public void sendPost(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }


}
```

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: @Isac não dá erro, ele simplesmente não me retorna nada, quando na verdade ele deveria me retornar o resultado da minha requisição post, que no meu caso seria uma string no formato JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Da uma olhada mas acho q está faltando no somente essa linha no seu código:

```
conn.setDoInput(true);
```

Mas sempre usei esse código abaixo:

```
URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);


OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

writer.write(PARAMETROS.toString());

writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: obrigado por responder robson, tentei a sua sugestão de colocar o `conn.setDoInput(true)`, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Esse segundo código que você postou tem retorno dos dados de uma requisição post com parâmetros? Em que formato eu devo colocar os parâmetros no `PARAMETROS.toString()` ?

Comment: Sim ela retorna dados. Cara com essa linha mostra o tipo dos dados que são recebidos no webservice. `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");` eu recebo os parâmetros no web service em formato json. Teria que alterar para ver o tipo de dados que você recebe.